# How to update IE on old WinXP system?

Tags: windows-xp

There is a old computer here that is running WinXP and IE7 (yes, 7).  I'd like to update it IE8, which is the latest version that is allowed to run on WinXP.  I know support for XP has ended, but I thought support ending meant no new releases, not that you can't download anything at all.  The Microsoft web site only brings up a screen saying support has ended whenever trying to update anything on XP.

So does "support ending" mean you can't download anything, or are the last versions available somewhere?  If so, where?

Comment: Windows Update.

Comment: @Michael: I don't understand.  I went to the Microsoft web site to update IE and only got the blurb about XP support having ended.  There was no option that I could see to download the last version from before support ended.

Comment: Go to Windows Update. It's in the Start Menu. It might also be named Microsoft Update.

Comment: Windows XP should still update as of 2014, though there are no new security fixes.

You *should* still be able to download IE from microsoft if it isn't automatically updating.

As a longer term solution I suggest finding out, and getting the last version of windows offline update (V9.2.1), and an *offline* installer for IE that supported XP and keeping a repo of updates yourself for a rainy day, or just upgrading to a supported OS

Comment: A side note, xp embedded is still supported, and customer who brought a support extension. So, like other tell windows update should find it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. However, I would still recommend to try Firefox or Chrome as they are much safer, up-to-date and patched than IE8. If it is an old PC, with low RAM, I would not try Chrome; but an old version of Firefox should work way better and faster than IE. Unless, you need it to use some kind of old software or website designed for IE especially. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could try downloading an offline installer from the links provided here:

http://appsonpc.com/download-ie8-offline-installer-windows-xp

Since they link to microsoft.com, I presume that they are safe to install. 
As safe as IE8 is, anyway ;-)

Good luck!

Comment: That appsonpc.com site downloads an exe that tries to get you to install a bunch of crapware, then doesn't supply the offline ie8 installer!  I would down vote if I had enough juju!!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.itechtics.com/download-internet-explorer-all-versions
provided
http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/C/0/CC0BD555-33DD-411E-936B-73AC6F95AE11/IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe
which did work. Consider that as a less roundabout way than coming at it via windows update.

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: The second link gave me an "Installing Windows Internet Explorer 8" dialog on my old XP system.  It went through Downloading, Checking for malicious software, Installing IE8, Installing updates and Finishing setup. I only need IE so that Windows Update works (it doesn't work with IE7).

Comment: The microsoft link worked for me, I know I shouldn't be using XP, but testing on a dev VM for site compatibility as we still have users using XP (mostly in public sector!..)

Answer (score 1):

As both Michael Hampton and Journeyman Geek mentioned in comments (I would have been happy to upvote and accept either as a answer), Windows Update still works on XP, and automatically updates IE to version 8.  I tried this and it worked.

However, Windows Update is not necessarily in the Start menu.  You can reliably get to the Windows Update page by going to Control Panel, then Automatic Updates.

Comment: Yeah, but even if you go through the control panel, it starts IE to do the update.  So you need a working IE, and if you have ie7, it just says it's not supported.